# Flutter: get user data on refresh from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase login with Google and before updating to Flutter 2 everything was working fine: user could log in and get his data from Firebase. On refresh he would get his data again.

Right now the second last doesn't work, I get null on refresh

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print(authService.getUser()); // this is null here

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I'm checking the docs to see if something changed but I don't see any difference. How could  I load everything AFTER I get the user info from Firebase?

Video of the issue:
https://youtu.be/dz0rSTCU9u8

Comment: Have the same problem with Flutter Web since upgrading to flutter 2

Comment: did you update to latest version? I'm trying right now and it seems fine

Answer (score 0):

You can [listen for the auth state to change](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) and respond to that:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseAuth.instance
    .authStateChanges()
    .listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
      } else {
        print('User is signed in!');
      }
      runApp(MyApp());
    });
}
```

If you only want to run the app if the user has signed in, you can move the call to `runApp` into the `if` block.

Comment: I get the same behaviour: it never enters in != null, it doesn't wait to get the user, but I can get it after a few seconds

Comment: I recorded the problem: https://youtu.be/dz0rSTCU9u8

Comment: your code works when I actively sign it, but not on refresh. When the white page with the text appears that means that the user is logged in but I fetch his data in _MyHomePageState()'s initState, that's why it seems logged but there is not data

Comment: `.authStateChanges()` fires upon a reload of the app/page too. You can verify that by checking the output of the print statements in the code snippet I shared. If you're having a hard time then showing the correct data after that, I recommend posting another question that shows how you load that data.

Comment: There is not "User is signed in!" message on that video when I refresh the app (0:13). This question is related to that already

Comment: Interesting. So if you run in a debugger and set a breakpoint on `if (user == null) {`, does it not get called at all when the app restarts?

Comment: nope, exactly what I showed in the video above